# Google sheets - QUERY, IMPORTRANGE and append text to results

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet (sheetA) that contains master data. I am importing this data into another google sheet (Sheet B) using "IMPORTRANGE" function along with "QUERY"

```
=SORT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url for sheet A","Crown DB!A2:E"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE not(Col5='SS')"))
```

Suppose, following is an example output I get after runnning the above formula

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

I want to append text to these returned values so that I can obtain two new values for each returned value:

```
item1 - var1
item1 - var2
item2 - var1
item2 - var2
item3 - var1
item3 - var2
item4 - var1
item4 - var2
```

If it were a single variant, I can just append "- Var1" to the above formula:

`SORT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url for sheetA","Crown DB!A2:E"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE not(Col5='SS')")) & "- Var1"`

How can I modify the formula to get append multiple variants (>=2) for each item returned using IMPORTRANGE? The number of variants for each item is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach is by appending the values inside an array formula and flatten it. Then use SORT afterwards.

#### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(FLATTEN(
QUERY({A2:E},"SELECT Col1 WHERE not(Col5='SS') and not(Col1='')")
 & {" - Val1", " - Val2"})))
```

#### Output (2 variants):

[image: output1]

#### Output (3 variants):

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- Used `{A2:E}` to show the full formula easier in testing. Change `{A2:E}` into the `IMPORTRANGE` in your case.
- `not(Col1='')` is important to skip rows with blank Col1's.
- Appending an n-array with an m-array in the `ARRAYFORMULA` will result into `n x m` dimension of array. Using `FLATTEN` on that will combine them all in one column. Then we use `SORT` afterwards.

#### Final formula should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("url for sheetA","Crown DB!A2:E"),
"SELECT Col1 WHERE not(Col5='SS') and not(Col1='')"
) & {" - Val1", " - Val2"})))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works "FLATTEN" was what I was looking for. I have used "ARRAYFORMULA" before.